# Angular Output dinâmicos. Será isso possível?

Tags: angular, typescript

Antes de mais, desculpem o meu português, não o escrevo bem e estou a usar um tradutor, mas consigo lê-lo suficientemente bem.

Tenho vários componentes pai e criei um componente filho comum para todos eles que deve adaptar-se de forma dinâmica e automática a cada caso, entre eles vários botões que serão gerados com uma testa usando os dados enviados pelo pai (nome, classe CSS e nome de Saída).

A questão é: Posso criar Output de uma forma dinâmica que aponte directamente para a função do progenitor correspondente?

Uma solução rápida que me ocorre é usar apenas uma saída que envia uma corda ou se integra sempre à mesma função do pai e que esta a interpreta e a deriva para a função correspondente com um interruptor mas parece-me uma solução não muito "elegante" e eficiente.

Por agora tentei fazer isto na componente filho, mas o próprio editor dá-me um erro:

componenteHijo.components.ts

```
@Input() misBotones: any[];
constructor() {
    this.misBotones.forEach(array => {
      @Output() array.nombreVariable: EventEmitter<number>;
    });
}
```

É claro que estou a enviar da componente principal uma matriz com todos os dados necessários:

componentePadre.components.html

```
<app-componente-hijo [misBotones]="botonesArray"></app-componente-hijo>
```

Comment: melhor seria um só que vc muda o dado de acordo com o botão

Comment: Sim, mas pode ser um botão ou mais do que um.

Answer (score -1):

Finalmente, com a ajuda das pessoas do **"Stack Overflow en Español"** (Stack Overflow en Espanhol) encontrei a solução.

**1-** Output dinâmicos não pode ser usada por uma razão simples: as anotações/decorações @Input e @Output são usadas em tempo de compilação, não em tempo de execução.

Não existem em Javascript e são utilizados para adicionar funcionalidades extra em tempo de compilação, pelo que não se pode modificar dinamicamente o código em tempo de execução.

**2-** Como alternativa a isto, pode usar o eventHandler:

A componente pai, dentro dos dados que prepara para a componente filho exibir, pode adicionar uma função a ser executada em resposta a um evento sobre esse elemento a ser criado.

No exemplo, é criada uma matriz de dados que tem objectos com duas propriedades: eventHandler e texto.

A componente criança recebe essa matriz e cria uma série de botões e, em resposta ao evento de clique, executa a função contida no eventHandler.

**Componente padre**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {

  data = [
    {
      eventHandler: () => {
        alert("boton 1");
      },
      text: "boton 1"
    },
    {
      eventHandler: () => {
        alert("boton 2");
      },
      text: "boton 2"
    }
  ];
  
}
```

**Componente hijo**

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "hello",
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let d of data">
      <button (click)="d.eventHandler()">{{ d.text }}</button>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      h1 {
        font-family: Lato;
      }
    `
  ]
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() data: any[];
}
```

[Link para a pergunta em espanhol](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/414408/angular-output-din%C3%A1micos-es-posible)